# Wrong usage of th tag

Tags: html, tablerow, tableheader

We just wrote a basic `html` code but it gives one outputs when `th` is used and gives and another output when `tr` is used

**This is the actual output** (with `tr`)

```html
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
 <td align="center" width="50%"><b>FIRST DEGREE PROGRAMMES (AIDED PROGRAMMES)</b></td>
 <td align="center" width="50%"><b>FIRST DEGREE PROGRAMMES (UNAIDED PROGRAMMES)</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td valign="top">
     <table border="1" style=" border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
      <th width="5%">No</th>
      <th width="10%">DEGREE</th>
      <th width="30%">PROGRAMME</th>
      <th width="55%">COMPLEMENTARY COURSE</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>B.Sc</td>
      <td>Botany &amp; Biotechnology</td>
      <td>1. Biochemistry</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>B.Com</td>
             <td>Commerce</td>
      <td>1. Finance/Computer Applications/Co-operation (Electives)</td>
  </tr>
     </table>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
     <table border="1" style=" border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
      <th width="5%">No</th>
      <th width="10%">DEGREE</th>
      <th width="30%">PROGRAMME</th>
      <th width="55%">COMPLEMENTARY COURSE</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>B.Com</td>
      <td>Commerce</td>
      <td>1. Finance (Electives)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>B.Com</td>
      <td>B.Com Accounts &amp; Audit (Self Financing) </td>
      <td>1. Accounts &amp; Audit (Electives)</td>
  </tr>
     </table>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

**This is the confusing output** (with `th`)

```html
<table width="100%">
 <th>
  <td align="center" width="50%"><b>FIRST DEGREE PROGRAMMES (AIDED PROGRAMMES)</b></td>
  <td align="center" width="50%"><b>FIRST DEGREE PROGRAMMES (UNAIDED PROGRAMMES)</b></td>
 </th>
 <tr>
  <td valign="top">
   <table border="1" style=" border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
     <th width="5%">No</th>
     <th width="10%">DEGREE</th>
     <th width="30%">PROGRAMME</th>
     <th width="55%">COMPLEMENTARY COURSE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>B.Sc</td>
     <td>Botany &amp; Biotechnology</td>
     <td>1. Biochemistry</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>B.Com</td>
     <td>Commerce</td>
     <td>1. Finance/Computer Applications/Co-operation (Electives)</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
   <table border="1" style=" border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
     <th width="5%">No</th>
     <th width="10%">DEGREE</th>
     <th width="30%">PROGRAMME</th>
     <th width="55%">COMPLEMENTARY COURSE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>1</td>
     <td>B.Com</td>
     <td>Commerce</td>
     <td>1. Finance (Electives)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>B.Com</td>
     <td>B.Com Accounts &amp; Audit (Self Financing) </td>
     <td>1. Accounts &amp; Audit (Electives)</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>   
</table>
```

We are confused why there is an extra `td` coming when we use `th` for main table. If you are viewing using a `UC Browser`, you can simply press `Ctrl` button and click on the browser output which will give you the actual table layout. So in first output there will only two `td`s and for second output there will be three `td`'s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `<th>` is a table cell. Including table cells (`<td>`) inside table cells (`<th>`) will give you unexpected results. What you are looking for is `<thead>`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead

As a boilerplate, you can define tables as below:

```
<table>
  <!-- header -->
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header content 1</th>
      <th>Header content 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!-- body -->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Body content 1</td>
      <td>Body content 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for correcting me, that one clarified my concept